# python Split Dataframe based first occurrence

Tags: python, pandas

Hello  I am trying to split a data frame into 2:
first data frame should have all the rows occurred first and remaining all occurrences into another table. please see below sample input data frame and output data frames i am looking for:
i will sort data by group and number before i split

#### input data:

```
Group               number

Short               1
Short               2
Moderate            55
Moderate            31
Tall                24
Tall                11
yellow              101
```

#### Dataframe 1

```
Group              Number
Short                1
Moderate            55
Tall                24
Yellow              101
```

#### Dataframe 2

```
Group           Number
Short             2
moderate          31
Tall              11
```

Please advice how i can solve this problem. if its duplicate Question please point to any solution which is already provided.

Thanks

Comment: I'd say it's not a dupe of the linked  Q since here the entries are sorted which can be exploited in a solution,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `groupby` and `first` for df1:

```
df1 = df.reset_index().groupby('Group', as_index=False).first().set_index('index')
```

for df2, then you do:

```
df2 = df.drop(df1.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

`drop_duplicates` can be used to keep the first occurrences and the rest can be sliced by excluding those indexes:

```
first_occ = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Group', keep='first')

rest = df[~df.index.isin(first_occ.index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can exploit the fact that your df is sorted like so:

```
>>> df[df['Group'] != df['Group'].shift(1)]
      Group  number
0     Short       1
2  Moderate      55
4      Tall      24
6    yellow     101
>>> df[df['Group'] == df['Group'].shift(1)]
      Group  number
1     Short       2
3  Moderate      31
5      Tall      11
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than two you can use this code to capture each instance:

```
df_set = df.set_index(df.groupby('Group').cumcount(), append=True).swaplevel(0,1)
```

#### First Occurance:

```
df_set.loc[0]
```

Output:

```
      Group  number
0     Short       1
2  Moderate      55
4      Tall      24
6    yellow     101
```

#### Second Occurance:

```
df_set.loc[1]
```

Output:

```
      Group  number
1     Short       2
3  Moderate      31
5      Tall      11
```

And so on incrementing the index for loc of the df_set.